# TempData does not persist on pass to second action

Tags: c#, tempdata

I'm trying to pass `TempData` through a couple actions, but I can't get it to persist beyond one pass. I've read a ton of questions on StackOverflow about this, but I just can't get their solutions to work. I know `TempData` only persists for one redirect, but it is suggested that .Keep() or .Peek() should allow it to persist on another redirect. That unfortunately has not worked for me. I have also tried reassigning `TempData` and straight hard-coding of `TempData` from the second redirect and it still will not pass through. I'm obviously missing something. My code:

```
//First redirect
 public ActionResult Index(int? userId, int? reportingYear)
    {
        if (Session["State"] == null)
        {
            TempData["Timeout"] = "Your session has timed out. Please login to continue.";
            return RedirectToAction("LogOff", "Account");
        }
    }

//Second redirect
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        //Delete the application cookie and clear session variables
        var cookies = Request.Cookies;
        List<string> tempCookies = new List<string>();

        foreach (string cookie in cookies)
        {
            if (cookie.ToString() != "quailCoord")
            {
                tempCookies.Add(cookie);
            };
        }

        foreach (string cookie in tempCookies)
        {
            HttpCookie deleteCookie = Request.Cookies[cookie];
            deleteCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(deleteCookie);
        }

        Session.Abandon();
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        
        //When checking that the key exists, it does and enters the if statement to keep the data
        if (TempData.ContainsKey("Timeout")
        {
            TempData.Keep("Timeout");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

//Third action
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        //It does not find any TempData keys
        if (TempData.ContainsKey("Timeout"))
        {
            ViewBag.Timeout = TempData["Timeout"] as string;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I have also attempted these in place of the `TempData.Keep("Timeout")` method:

`TempData.Peek("Timeout")`

`TempData["Timeout"] = TempData["Timeout"]`

`TempData["Timeout"] = "Your session has timed out. Please login to continue."`

None of these methods pass to the `Login()` action. `TempData` is always empty upon entering that action. When debugging, the minute I step over the `return RedirectToAction("Login")` line, the count in TempData turns to 0. What am I missing? Is deleting the cookies a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `TempData` will store data in `Session` object which might store [SessionId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid?view=netframework-4.8) in cookie, if you delete that server will create another [SessionId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid?view=netframework-4.8) (object) for you instead of the original one.

so that if you want to keep `TempData` to multiple actions we might need to keep [SessionId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid?view=netframework-4.8) value from the cookie.

From your code, we can try to add
a judgement to check cookie key whether if yes don't delete the cookie.

```
foreach (string cookie in cookies)
{
    if (cookie.ToString() != "quailCoord" && cookie.ToString() != "ASP.NET_SessionId")
    {
        tempCookies.Add(cookie);
    };
}
```

Comment: Almost worked - I had to change your line to `if (cookie.ToString() != "ASP.NET_SessionId")` because the cookie is the name of the cookie and not the value. I also had to remove the `Session.Abandon()` line. The problem with this is that I don't think Chrome will let go of the cookies upon closing the browser without logging off, which was the purpose of deleting all those cookies in the first place. Perhaps another if statement can be used... Regardless, update your answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: @MKF Yes `ASP.NET_SessionId` was the default session key in cookie, I edit my answer